# F5 OneConnect with non-HTTP traffic

Tags: f5, big-ip

Is it possible to use F5 OneConnect with non-http traffic?  It seems like it might be possible to create iRules that can figure out when to attach/detach, but I haven't seen any examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its possible. 
As per F5 AskF5 [SOL7208](http://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/solutions/public/7000/200/sol7208.html):

```
The OneConnect profile may be used with any TCP protocol, 
but will function only when applied to virtual servers that 
are processing simple request/response protocols where 
transaction boundaries are explicitly obvious, such as those 
in which each request and each response is contained within 
a single packet.
```

So it would still depend on the protocol that you want to load-balance. What protocol are you going to load balance?

Comment: It is a custom sockets protocol.  The request/response will use more than one packet.  My thought is that I can use iRules to scan the request and response and trigger attach/detach when it sees the start/end.